# Abscissa, Ordinate and ?? for z-axis?

Tags: terminology, coordinate-systems

Like x-axis is abscissa, y-axis is ordinate what is z-axis called?

It is one of basic doubts from my childhood.

Comment: Even I have that doubt!

Comment: Applicate, or something like that.

Comment: The problem of using many names is to think in the n-dimensional case for example, the names are not important.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It apparently is called "applicate". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system for reference.

> For 3D diagrams, the names "abscissa" and "ordinate" are rarely used for x and y, respectively. When they are, the z-coordinate is sometimes called the applicate. The words abscissa, ordinate and applicate are sometimes used to refer to coordinate axes rather than the coordinate values.

Which again refers to https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cartesian_orthogonal_coordinate_system .

Comment: +1 Nice answer, I will wait some more time for better suggestion then I will accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: What about a 4th dimension. I guess a quaternion should live in such a space, shouldn't it?