# Is there a better name for a 'three-dimensional coordinate system'?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I am wondering if there is a commonly agreed name for any system that makes use of three coordinates. Something that includes 'geographical coordinate system', 'spherical coordinate system', 'celestial coordinat system' and all the likes.
Or is 'three-dimensional coordinate system' the answer?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"3-space" is sometimes used. See:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space?wprov=sfla1

Regarding Cartesian coördinates in a 2-space, it is well-known that the x- and y-coördinates are called, respectively, the "abscissa" and "ordinate." Less well-known is that, in a 3-space, the z-coördinate is called the "applicate."
[Abscissa, Ordinate and ?? for z-axis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166142)

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is sometimes called *space*, so I suppose you could use *spatial coordinate system.*  But other than that, I can't think of a name for a coordinate system with three dimensions besides “three-dimensional coordinate system.”